# Can not install mysql ubuntu after removing maria db

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I was working on mysql database, and unfortunately I installed mariadb and when I want to go back to mysql I have error , I removed mariadb and trying to install mysql with this command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but I have this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
     2 not fully installed or removed.
  After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
  Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't 
exist
 dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
  mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
 Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a 
  followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.7
   mysql-server
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I can not re install mysql , what can I do , I looked for solution but don't have result

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a purge, then re-install.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```